# why ListView must be wrapped by MaterialApp?

Tags: listview, flutter

I want to know why in flutter, Listview is different from Text that it can't be returned directly to **runApp()**.

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.amber[600],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

if ListView wrapped in MaterialApp, it worked. However, if it was returned directly or in a Container, like below:

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.amber[600],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I got errors.
I have read lots of articles about flutter including the Listview api of official doc, but nobody explains the reason. Althrough someone has commit an issue in github(https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50947), the solver only told him how to fix the issue without the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ListView expects that text direction is defined. MaterialApp is defining that for you, but if you don't want to use it - you can do it yourself using [Directionality](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html).

ListView needs that property for computing which way scrolling should be.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Row One'),
        Text('Row Two'),
        Text('Row Three'),
        Text('Row Four'),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```